# scp stdin: is not a tty, and write failed, connection reset by peer

Tags: linux, scp, cygwin

I have used scp for years between linux servers, as well as with Mac OSX systems.  But now, I have installed cygwin and ssh, bash and openssl in order to pull large files from my linux box on the web to my Windows 7 laptop.

It's cool to have commands like ls, cd etc. on my Windows machine, but when running this command:

```
scp -r -p -P xxxx root@myserver.com:/tmp/mysqldump .
```

I get the following two messages:

```
stdin: is not a tty
```

Then download begins and at anywhere from 2% to 8% complete I get:

```
Write failed: Connection reset by peer
lost connection
```

in this file `~/.bascrc` I commented out `mesg y` and it suppressed the first message (which I don't think helped at all anyway to do so) but the second remains.

I'm assuming it has something to do with how the windows TTY talks to the Linux machine but I'm not expert enough to be sure.  I have searched this extensively and the only fix I found was in trying to comment out that line in ~/.bashrc.

Due to the size of these files scp is the only viable option.

Comment: How large are these files? Larger than 2GB?

Comment: yes, they are anywhere from 2 to 3.5GB

Comment: I suspect one side has an `scp` that uses 32-bit numbers and can't correctly handle files larger than 2GB. As a workaround, you might be able to use `split` to chop them into smaller pieces.

Comment: that seems to be the case as an import of a small 5K file worked.  Since it stopped at around 8 or 9%, I'll need to split the file into 20 chunks.

Comment: Try splitting with a size of 2100000000. That's less than 2^31.